# Getting "This row already belongs to another table & Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

if I used `finalTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)` it gives me this error `"Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."`

```
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers";
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
DataTable finalTable = new DataTable();
//finalTable.TableName = "Customers";
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    int i = 1;
    DataTable firstTable = ds.Tables[0];
    //firstTable.TableName = "Customers";
    foreach (DataRow row in firstTable.Rows)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            firstTable.NewRow();
            i = 0;
        }
        finalTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
        i++;
    }
}

Repeater1.DataSource = finalTable;
Repeater1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

and if i used this `finalTable.Rows.Add(row)`, it gives me `"This row already belongs to another table".`

```
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers";
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    DataTable finalTable = new DataTable();
    //finalTable.TableName = "Customers";
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        int i = 1;
        DataTable firstTable = ds.Tables[0];
        //firstTable.TableName = "Customers";
        foreach (DataRow row in firstTable.Rows)
        {
            if (i == 5)
            {
                firstTable.NewRow();
                i = 0;
            }
            finalTable.Rows.Add(row);
            i++;
        }
    }

    Repeater1.DataSource = finalTable;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

don't know how to solve it, any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

below is a method that allow you select data from your database by TSQL (select * from table1 ...) then return as datatable and continue processing  (eg , bind table)

**This is how**

1) built a connection string , If you are developing web apps , go to web.config file add below , change parameter according your SQL environment setup.

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>  
        <add name="PSDatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=YourSQLserverName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

....

2) then build a method to accept SQL statement and return multiple rows data as datatable . In below code , you do not need to define your datatable column structure , SQL will dynamic built it based on your SQL select statement

```
    public static DataTable RunSQL_DML_FillDataGrid(string TSQL)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PSDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


    try
    {
        // Run TSQL on SQL server
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(TSQL, connectionString);

        // MS Term ' Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
        // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
        // update the database.

        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        // Populate a new data table and return the table.
        // MS Term ' Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

3) Finally , you can bind your data table to other object ( datagridview , datatable ....) . I do not know what object type is Repeater1 inside your code but if it can accept datatable , then it shall bind correctly using the returned datatable